# Receiving the application URL. Django

Tags: python, django

I need to get the current URL of my application in my views.py. Not the bookmark I am in but the address to the home page (all).

I finded this solution:

```
url = "{0}://{1}".format(request.scheme, request.get_host())
```

But i but I think it can be simpler . Not using 'request ....' twice and by obtaining an interpretation of one variable.

Any good suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `request.build_absolute_uri('')`?

Comment: it's return 'h t t p ://127.0.0.1:8000/aaa/bbb/ccc/' i need only 'h t t p ://127.0.0.1:8000/'

Comment: Are you inputting an empty string (`''`) like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = request.build_absolute_uri("/")
```

See [the Django documentation reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri):

> Returns the absolute URI form of **`location`**. If no location is provided, the location will be set to `request.get_full_path()`.
>
> If the location is already an absolute URI, it will not be altered. Otherwise the absolute URI is built using the server variables available in this request.

This seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: No i need somethin like this 'h t t p ://127.0.0.1:8000' only not '/aaa/bbb/vvv'

Comment: @MaddieGraham Try `request.build_absolute_uri()`.

Comment: it's return 'h t t p ://127.0.0.1:8000/aaa/bbb/ccc/' i need only 'h t t p ://127.0.0.1:8000/'

Comment: @MaddieGraham See my edit, this will most likely get what you are asking for. Pass in a `"/"` to `build_absolute_uri`.